# how space complexity of this code is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

```
    public static boolean isUniqueChars2(String str) {
        boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i);
            if (char_set[val])
                return false;

            char_set[val] = true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It isn't. It's `O(1)`.

Comment: `new boolean[str.length()]` makes no sense...

Comment: @TedHopp -- If he did that, his program would crash for a string shorter than 65 characters containing the letter 'A'.  IOW, that suggestion is not pedagogical.

Comment: I hate text books now ...because from which I was reading says that it has O(n) ,I knew it isn't but wasn't sure...
Thank you very much

please can anyone suggest a good link for exercise of space complexity

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt - Oops. Absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your input is obviously O(n), but the memory requirements of this function is O(1), since the array has constant size. The time complexity is O(n) though, since it iterates over the string..

Comment: I think that the time complexity is also O(1) : There will never be more than ~26 steps, depending on the encoding and presence of special chars

Answer (score 1):

Not counting the input string, the code has `O(1)` space complexity. It consumes a constant amount of space irrespective of the input.

The time complexity is also `O(1)`, since the loop will never execute more than 256 steps.

Comment: @Betlista - The function exits when the first repeated character is found or the input is exhausted. No repeated characters is the worst case. (Note, however, that by the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there can't be more than 256 unique characters.)

Comment: Technically, the loop must exit after 256 iterations, independent of the input string, so it's worst case O(1) time.